# FFmpeg graph2dot tool

Tags: ffmpeg

In FFmpeg Filters Documentation is the section [3 graph2dot](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#graph2dot) is this about `graph2dot` program:

> The graph2dot program included in the FFmpeg tools directory can be used to parse a filtergraph description and issue a corresponding textual representation in the dot language.

I have FFmpeg from [Zeranoe's build](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (Windows, 64-bit, static) and I have no `tools` directory.

So I tried find this program by Google for downloading it but without success.

Is this part of the documentation *obsolete* or is it possible to obtain this program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't use Windows, but in Linux you can [download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) the FFmpeg source, then:

```
cd ffmpeg
./configure
make
make tools/graph2dot
```

Then you can use it:

```
echo "nullsrc,scale=640:360,nullsink" | tools/graph2dot -o graph.tmp
dot -Tpng graph.tmp -o graph.png
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Not Windows specific, but maybe helpful for any Linux user who also wants to use this tool.

Comment: I should note that I get an error for `make tools/graph2dot` on Windows with mingw-w64 with a vanilla source tree: "target not defined" or something like that. This is just after I built ff* binaries. I had to add graph2dot to the start of TOOLS and then `make alltools`.

Comment: Note: for Windows build, use `make tools/graph2dot.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

I maintain a Windows build of graph2dot and other tools at https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/. Look in the tools section.